# SONATA ADMIN BUNDLE CREATE A BLOCK HOME PAGE

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a little problem to realize my own block on the home page of the dashboard. I tried to follow this tutorial : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/your_first_block.html

But I have get the following error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   block service `sonata.block.service...` does not exist") in ...

Has someone else experienced this same issue, and/or knows how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the 4.6. SERVICE chapter from that tutorial? Make sure you have not misspelled something there.

And maybe if you'll post here your service declaration and the content from config.yml might help.

Comment: My service :                                                                                                  services:
    sonata.block.service.lastrequests:
          class: Emoovio\back\Bundle\Block\LastRequestService
          tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }
          arguments:
            - "sonata.block.service.statistics"                                                    and My config.yml :                                                                          sonata_block:
    blocks:
        [...]
        sonata.block.service.allrequests:

Comment: I see you have sonata.block.service.allrequests in your config.yml and sonata.block.service.lastrequests in your services.yml . Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: @Stev post your comment as an answer, so the question could be `answered` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have `sonata.block.service.allrequests` in your <kbd>config.yml</kbd> and `sonata.block.service.lastrequests` in your <kbd>services.yml</kbd>. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: It's exactly the problem. Sorry for this misspelled error. Thank you.